# Pygame get stuck

Tags: python, pygame

I have code that i run in visual studio code with the extension pygame, but i have realy much lag! I don't know what to do about it, here is the code:

```
import pygame, sys

pygame.init()
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

screen_width = 900
screen_height = 600
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((screen_width,screen_height))
pygame.display.set_caption('Hungry Plant')

bird = pygame.Rect(screen_width/2 - 15,screen_height/2 - 15,30,30)
player = pygame.Rect(screen_width/2 - 25, screen_height/1.20,50,300)

bg_color = pygame.Color('grey12')
light_grey = (200,200,200)
light_green = (144, 238, 144)

bird_speed_x = 7

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()

        bird.x += bird_speed_x

        if bird.left <= 0 or bird.right >= screen_width:
            bird_speed_x *= -1

        screen.fill(bg_color)
        pygame.draw.rect(screen,light_green, player)
        pygame.draw.ellipse(screen, light_grey, bird)

        pygame.display.flip()
        clock.tick(30)
```

I have tried to find a solution online, but it was unsuccessful!

Answer (score 1):

It is a matter of [Indentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#indentation). You have to draw the scene in the application loop, not in the event loop. The application loop is executed once per frame, but the event loop is executed only when an event occurs.

```py
while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()

    # indentation
    #<--|

    bird.x += bird_speed_x
    if bird.left <= 0 or bird.right >= screen_width:
        bird_speed_x *= -1

    screen.fill(bg_color)
    pygame.draw.rect(screen,light_green, player)
    pygame.draw.ellipse(screen, light_grey, bird)

    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(30)
```